# WPF parent window & child window interaction

Tags: c#, wpf

I have opened a window (let's call it window1) first, then from this parent window two child windows are being opened. Now I want to close window1 once windows 2 and 3 are closed (i.e. they have completed their work).

I have tried calling a method in the parent window upon the window close event of either of the child windows and I maintain a static variable to ensure both windows are closed. The thing is I'm unable to close the parent window though the method is being invoked.

So please explain how to do this.

My Code:

```
//Parent window Creating child windows
private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   Window2 w2= new Window2();
   Window3 w3= new Window3();
   w2.Show();
   w3.Show();
}
// Calling the parent window method upon window closeevent from child windows

private void Window_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Window1 w1=new Window1(); 
    w1.method1();              
}
// parent window method

private void method1()
{
    count++; //global static var
    MessageBox.Show("BUT THIS GETS DISPLAYED");
    if (count==2)
    {
        this.Close(); // doesnt work;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just how do you figure that Window1 w1=new Window1() is the parent Window?  New is new.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not laid out in classes so its a hard to tell but I'm presuming the windows_closed code is in the child window? If not you are missing subscribing to the child window closed event in the parent windows code.

Problem is you are making a new instance of Window1 to call method1 - so the count will only ever reach one.

One easy way would be to make method1 static, so you don't need to make an instance of Window1 from the child window to call it.

try this

```
//this should be in Window1.cs
public static void method1()
{
count++;//global static var
MessageBox.Show("BUT THIS GETS DISPLAYED");
if(count==2)
{
this.Close(); // doesnt work;
}
}

//this should be in childwindow.cs
private void Window_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Window1.method1();              
}
```

Note - making the method static is perhaps not the best way of doing it - but I'm assuming you are quite new to this so it will do while you are learning.

Comment: The method Window_Closed indeed exists in the childwindow class and the problem is that method1 is getting invoked and the count value too gets updated but it isnt possible access any element or its properties and hence couldnt close the parent window

Comment: As course it gets invoked - but as you have made a new instance of Window1 to call method1 it is not the same instance as the Window1 that opened the child window.

Comment: @priyanka That is why you need to make the method static.  Did you even try this solution?

Comment: @Blam Yes i tried. When the method is made static its not possible to access any element (specifically couldn't refer this ptr )

Comment: @priyanka ptr?  What is ptr? If want a fix then ask specific questions.

Comment: @Blam refer code section i meant this.Close property

Comment: @Blam Nor it is possible to get reference to any ui element

Comment: @priyanka Close is a method not a property.  I know how how to fix this but based on your lack of effort I am not going to help you.